# Strictness of completion implies strictness.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-groups

Let $\phi:G \rightarrow H$ be a morphism of (semi-)normed groups. Then $\phi$ is said to be strict if the natural isomorphism $G/\ker(\phi)\rightarrow \mathrm{Im}(\phi)$ is a homeomorphism.

That means that $\phi$ is open onto its image.

By Proposition 4 in Chapter 1.1.9 of "Non-archimedean analysis" by Bosch, Güntzer, Remmert we know that if $\phi:G\rightarrow H$ is a strict morphism of (semi-)normed groups then so is the completion $\hat{\phi}: \hat{G}\rightarrow \hat{H}$.

Now I was wondering if the converse is also true?

EDIT: The (semi)-norm on the groups are ultrametric functions.

Answer (score 1):

NO. Consider a Banach space $(H,\|\cdot\|)$ and a strictly finer norm $\||\cdot\||$ on $H$ (this requires the axiom of choice which provides linear discontinuous functionals $\varphi:X\to \mathbb R$ so that we can take $\||x\||=\|x\|+|\varphi(x)|$). Let $\phi: G\to H$ be the identical map where $G=H$ is endowed with the finer norm $\||\cdot\||$. Then $\phi$ is not strict because the unit ball of $G$ is not open in $H$ but $\tilde \phi$ is strict because of the open mapping theorem (b.t.w., $\tilde\phi$ is not injective although so is $\phi$).

Comment: Why is the unit ball of G not open in $H$?

Comment: Then it would contain a ball $\{x\in H: \|x\|\le r\}$ so that $\|x\|\le r$ implies $\|| x\||\le 1$. This yields $\||x\||\le \frac 1r \|x\|$ by homogeneity of the norms: $\|a x\|=r$ for $a= r/\|x\|$ so that $\||ax\||\le 1$ and hence $\||x\||\le 1/a= \frac 1r \|x\|$. Hence both norms woulde be equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for more clarity, but I still have an uncertainty. Whats the reason for containing such a ball?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your last question, but the definition of an open set in a metric space says that every point is the center of a ball contained in the set.